# What will be the time complexity of reversing the linked list in a different way using below code?

Tags: linked-list, time-complexity

Given a linked List **$link1**, with elements (a->b->c->d->e->f->g->h->i->j), we need to reverse the linked list provided that the reversing will be done in a manner like -

Reverse 1st element (a)

Reverse next 2 elements (a->c->b)

Reverse next 3 elements (a->c->b->f->e->d)

Reverse next 4 elements  (a->c->b->f->e->d->j->i->h->g)

....

....

I have created below code in PHP to solve this problem

**Things I need -**

1. I need to calculate the time complexity of **reverseLinkedList** function below.
2. Need to know if we can optimize **reverseLinkedList** function to reduce time complexity.

-

```
class ListNode
{
    public $data;
    public $next;

    function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->next = NULL;
    }

    function read_node()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}

class LinkList
{
    private $first_node;
    private $last_node;
    private $count;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->first_node = NULL;
        $this->last_node = NULL;
        $this->count = 0;
    }

    function size()
    {
        return $this->count;
    }

    public function read_list()
    {
        $listData = array();
        $current = $this->first_node;
        while($current != NULL)
        {
            echo $current->read_node().' ';
            $current = $current->next;
        }
    }

    public function reverse_list()
    {
        if(($this->first_node != NULL)&&($this->first_node->next != NULL))
        {
            $current = $this->first_node;
            $new = NULL;

            while ($current != NULL)
            {
                $temp = $current->next;
                $current->next = $new;
                $new = $current;
                $current = $temp;
            }
            $this->first_node = $new;
        }
    }



    public function read_node($position)
    {
        if($position <= $this->count)
        {
            $current = $this->first_node;
            $pos = 1;
            while($pos != $position)
            {
                if($current->next == NULL)
                    return null;
                else
                    $current = $current->next;

                $pos++;
            }
            return $current->data;
        }
        else
            return NULL;
    }

    public function insert($data)
    {
        $new_node = new ListNode($data);

        if($this->first_node != NULL)
        {
            $this->last_node->next = $new_node;
            $new_node->next = NULL;
            $this->last_node = &$new_node;
            $this->count++;
        }
        else
        {
            $new_node->next = $this->first_node;
            $this->first_node = &$new_node;

            if($this->last_node == NULL)
                $this->last_node = &$new_node;

            $this->count++;
        }
    }
}


//Create linked list
$link1 = new LinkList();

//Insert elements
$link1->insert('a');
$link1->insert('b');
$link1->insert('c');
$link1->insert('d');
$link1->insert('e'); 
$link1->insert('f'); 
$link1->insert('g'); 
$link1->insert('h');
$link1->insert('i'); 
$link1->insert('j'); 

echo "<b>Input :</b><br>";       
$link1->read_list();


//function to reverse linked list in specified manner
function reverseLinkedList(&$link1)
{
    $size= $link1->size();

    if($size>2)
    {

        $link2=new LinkList();

        $link2->insert($link1->read_node(1));
        $elements_covered=1;

        //reverse
        $rev_size=2;

        while($elements_covered<$size)
        {
            $start=$elements_covered+1;
            $temp_link = new LinkList();
            $temp_link->insert($link1->read_node($start));

            for($i=1;$i<$rev_size;$i++)
            {
                $temp_link->insert($link1->read_node(++$start));
            }

            $temp_link->reverse_list();
            $temp_size=$temp_link->size();
            $link2_size=$link2->size();

            for($i=1;$i<=$temp_size;$i++)
            {
                $link2->insert($temp_link->read_node($i));
                ++$elements_covered;
                ++$link2_size;
            }
            ++$rev_size;
        }
        ///reverse 

        //Flip the linkedlist
        $link1=$link2;

    }    
}
///function to reverse linked list in specified manner

//Reverse current linked list $link1
reverseLinkedList($link1);

echo "<br><br><b>Output :</b><br>";       
$link1->read_list();
```

Comment: Are you trying to _reverse_ a linked list, or _sort_ one?  Also, does your code work, or are you asking about an alternative to what you are already using?

Comment: @gauravparmar.: check the answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am trying to reverse the linked list in a specified way. My code works. I was trying to get the time complexity of the function reverseLinkedList. Any better solution which can reverse the given linked list in the above mentioned way with lesser time complexity will be great.

Answer (score 2):

It's `O(n)`...just one traversal.

And secondly, here tagging it in language is not necessary.

I have provided a Pseudocode here for your reference:

```
  current => head_ref
  prev    => NULL;
  current => head_ref;
  next    => null;
  while (current != NULL)
  {
        next  = current->next;  
        current->next = prev;   
        prev = current;
        current = next;
  }
 *head_ref = prev;
```

Comment: Yes. It will be O(n) probably.

Comment: @gauravparmar.: It will be..not probably.

Comment: Can we reduce the time complexity in some way for this function reverseLinkedList?

Comment: @gauravparmar.: With O(1) space complexity and O(n) time complexity I guess it can't be modified further.

Comment: @coderrac : Inside reverseLinkedList, I am using read_node function multiple times in a loop which again has a loop and it goes to a particular position in the linked list and fetches the element at that key value by starting from head so will it not take O(n) separately and then on top of it we have while loop in reverseLinkedList i.e.  while($elements_covered<$size) which also runs for nearly around linkedlist size so will the time complexity O(n) be correct?

Comment: @gauravparmar.: This is something you are doing new? or the old one? and pls post the code if new one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144070/discussion-between-gauravparmar-and-coderredoc).